# cant open device

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a little problem. I install this module into my kernel and its written under /proc

When I try to open() it from user mode I get the following message:

> "Can't open device file: my_dev"

```
static int module_permission(struct inode *inode, int op, struct nameidata *foo)
{
 //if its write
 if ((op == 2)&&(writer == DOESNT_EXIST)){
  writer = EXIST ;
  return 0;
 }
 //if its read
 if (op == 4 ){
  numOfReaders++;
  return 0;
 }
 return -EACCES;
}

int procfs_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
 try_module_get(THIS_MODULE);
 return 0;
}

static struct file_operations File_Ops_4_Our_Proc_File = {
 .read   = procfs_read,
 .write   = procfs_write,
 .open   = procfs_open,
 .release = procfs_close,
};

static struct inode_operations Inode_Ops_4_Our_Proc_File = {
 .permission = module_permission, /* check for permissions */
};

int init_module()
{
 /* create the /proc file */
 Our_Proc_File = create_proc_entry(PROC_ENTRY_FILENAME, 0644, NULL);
 /* check if the /proc file was created successfuly */
 if (Our_Proc_File == NULL){
  printk(KERN_ALERT "Error: Could not initialize /proc/%s\n",
         PROC_ENTRY_FILENAME);
  return -ENOMEM;
 }

 Our_Proc_File->owner = THIS_MODULE;
 Our_Proc_File->proc_iops = &Inode_Ops_4_Our_Proc_File;
 Our_Proc_File->proc_fops = &File_Ops_4_Our_Proc_File;
 Our_Proc_File->mode = S_IFREG | S_IRUGO | S_IWUSR;
 Our_Proc_File->uid = 0;
 Our_Proc_File->gid = 0;
 Our_Proc_File->size = 80;

 //i added init the writewr status
 writer = DOESNT_EXIST;
 numOfReaders = 0 ;
 printk(KERN_INFO "/proc/%s created\n", PROC_ENTRY_FILENAME);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an `strace` of your open call to see the actual error returned? Do you have permission to open the device? If all of the above fail, use ftrace.

Answer (score 0):

```
open("/proc/ex3mod", O_WRONLY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Like the previous commenter said, you don't have permissions to open the proc file.  Try fixing the permissions with `chmod`.

Comment: although i use chmod o+w /proc/ex3mod 
i am still not permitted am i doing something wrong (most probably  )?

Comment: Ising  found my ERR
when I calculated op I used == instead of using &(logical AND )
as example: if (op & 4)